# How does 'ssh user2@host2:user1@host1' work?

Tags: ssh

In a setup that I have inherited, using the command `ssh user2@host2:user1@host1`, I can connect to user2@host2 through user1@host1 but I don't understand how it works (where is this ssh behaviour documented?)

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to setup my .ssh/config so that I can do ssh user2@host2 and it goes directly through the host1 and I believe it can be achieved using ProxyCommand but the following is a failure:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p user1@host1' user2@host2
user1's password:
Received disconnect from REDACTED_IP: 11: Bye Bye
Disconnected from REDACTED_IP
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after experimenting for some time, it appears that the software of `host1` (which I did not have direct access to) is configured so that `user2@host2:user1` is actually a username.

Hence `ssh user2@host2:user1@host1` works.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your `$HOME/.ssh/config` for record like `Host *:*`. If you want to know more how it works there is good article at [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Recursively_Chaining_an_Arbitrary_Number_of_Hosts) about that.
And for command line you use you should remove equal sign `=` from `ProxyCommand`:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user1@host1" user2@host2
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `=` between option name and value. Your version of the command will do exactly the same as the original version, but I find the original version to be a bit more readable than yours.